# Paid for up front and Part of what you’re “paying for” when I start a bounty

Tags: support, bounty

On the [bounty help page](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) the words "paid" and "paying" and the sentences

> All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances

and

> Part of what you’re “paying for” with the bounty is to get additional attention for your question, over and beyond what a normal question gets

as well as the word "spend" as in the sentences

> To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50)

and

> Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).

My question is: Do the words "paid" and "paying" mean that you have to pay money as in cash, credit card, etc, when I start a bounty and after I start a bounty if I am offering a bounty on a question that I have already posted an answer to, my minimum spend is 100 reputation and if I offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on), do I have to pay money as in cash, credit card, etc, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only currency on this site is reputation.

You spend reputation when you set up a bounty, and you earn reputation when a bounty is awarded to you.
Most reputation is earned through questions and answers, and that is how you should earn the reputation for a bounty.

No money is involved with using this site.
Nobody gets paid for answering or moderating, and nobody pays anything to get their questions answered.
You cannot exchange money for reputation; the only way to earn reputation is to contribute to this site through content that other users like.

Reputation does not work like money.
When you vote a question or answer up, you lose nothing but the recipient gains reputation points.
There is a small reputation fee for voting down an answer, and the recipient of a downvote loses reputation.
Bounties are the only money-like exception in the sense that one user gives an amount of reputation points to another user.

Nothing prevents payments of some form outside this site in order to get an answer here.
But offering to pay people off-site is unlikely work well, and such deals will have no effect on how this site itself works.
I recommend keeping off-site deals completely off-site unless you have a good sense of what might work here.
The only currency within this site is reputation.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is do the words Paid and paying mean that you have to pay money as in cash, credit card, etc,

No. The public Q&A sites, including Latin Stack Exchange, are completely free of charge. You don't have to pay money, we're all volunteers here and the company earns a little money with the advertisements.